# let user create content as another user

Tags: 7, nodes

My company has a website with a blog, and we have a virtual assistant.  Our process is that after writing the blog we have our virtual assistant proof read for grammar and spelling errors.  what we would like to do is to have our virtual assistant log into our site as herself but be able to post the blog article as one of us.

Is there a module that allows for this kind of ghost posting?

Answer (score 3):

Using node hooks to set the user will work, but what you are suggesting is really what is normally called "workflow" in content management systems.

There are a few ways to do workflow in Drupal, but the most common for Drupal 7 is probably using the [Workbench](https://drupal.org/project/workbench) suite of modules.  In particular, [Workbench Moderation](https://drupal.org/project/workbench_moderation) would be the most beneficial module for your situation.

You would set up a few different roles (writer, editor, proofreader, etc) for your users.  You would then set up various workflow states (Draft, Pending, and Published are a good start).  Then, you define which roles can push nodes through which states of the workflow.  For example, you may say that only writes can push from Draft to Pending, and proofreaders can only push from Pending to Published.

In the long run, this will give you the most flexibility as your current situation evolves and changes.

Answer (score 2):

First, while it is not mentioned, I assume that the content already exists as a node in the database (typed in by the original author), but that it  shall remain unpublished until the assistant has corrected it.  The following is based upon that assumption.

You can do this by creating a new role, e.g. `Assistant`, and then assign that role to the person you refer to as a "virtual assistant".

Then you download, install and enable the following module: [View unpublished](https://drupal.org/project/view_unpublished).

You now need to grant that role the following two permissions: `View unpublished` and `Edit any content` (both for the content types you want to enable this for.)  The settings for permissions and roles is under *Home » Administration » People*.

Now, the assistant should be able to navigate to `example.com/admin/content` and view the unpublished nodes queued up for review.  The assistant should be able click on a node and the the edit tab to edit it, and, when done, toggle the `Published` switch to publish the corrected node after review.  The byline will still be that of the original author, not of the assistant.

(If the node shall *not* remain unpublished until corrected, the workflow is even simpler.  Then you do not need to install a module, just grant the `Assistant` role the permission to `Edit any content`, and you're set to go.)

PS: Your question ask for a module that let your assistant log into our site as herself but then post a blog article masquerading as another user.  I doubt that this is what you're looking for (please edit your question to clarify this - also see my comment below your question), but *if* this is what you're after, there exists a module named [Masquerade](https://drupal.org/project/masquerade) that can do this.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming "virtual assistant" not as program but as a "real assistant". Having said that my idea is having user reference field on your blog post which will be a select list and when assistant will be posting the blog, she will select the user from the user reference field and then implementing [hook_node_presave()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.api.php/function/hook_node_presave/7) you can easily assign the author to the blog post as the user selected in the user reference field.

OR

you can give a try to [node override options module](https://drupal.org/project/override_node_options) which allows to have granular permissions for user role to change node author information.

Comment: The second option looks clean and apt. better to use the stuffs drupal provides by default.:)

Comment: True, @Neo surprisingly I realize it today we do not have granular permissions for authorizing info for content shipped in core!

Answer (score 1):

Can you use the module Masquerade?  https://drupal.org/project/masquerade

I use it on one of my projects for this exact reason.  Here's how it would work on my project to set up the permissions:

- Login to your site as an admin
- Go to People > Permissions
- Scroll down to Masquerade (you have to already have enabled the module).  Here you can test what permissions work for your users.  You do have to assign permissions to a role.  Maybe make a specific role for this type of user (https://drupal.org/node/120614)

As an admin, I can allow a single user to masquerade as another user by:

- Login to you site as an admin
- Go to your People page and find the user you want to allow to masquerade as others.  Select that user.
- My system has a prominent "edit" link to edit the profile. Select this.
- You will see a "Roles" option.  Since you have already set the roles that can have Masquerade as an option, select the role you wish to assign to this user.

That user should now be able to masquerade.  You might have to do some addition setup by assigning the Masquerade to a block or panel that is only visible to specific roles.

Hope that helps!